# Multiple maps crashing when switching to ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, duplicates, fragment, android-actionbaractivity

I am writing a small app which consists of fragments that have google maps in them. Fragments are added dynamically to main activity. Everything is fine when I use Activity, but when I switch to ActionBarActivity to make a custom toolbar, app crashes with this error:

`Binary XML file line #64: Duplicate id 0x7f0c005b, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`

Is there any way around this? Hope you can help.

Comment: Any chance you should be using `SupportMapFragment` with `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: Did u set unique names for fragments and all xml and java elements ?

Comment: SupportMapFragment doesn't change anything. Still crashes. I can't set unique ids - in fragment XML layout map has id "mapView" but I am dynamically adding more of these fragments to my layout in main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a solution. Instead of including MapFragment in parent fragment layout, I've moved the mapFragment to seperate fragment and now I'm adding it with childFragmentManager to the parent fragment. Now it works like a charm.